# ajax with jquery not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want when i click on button the  text input data post or get to `same page` that input is in it. i have this code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
         $("#btn_ok").click(function(){
              $.ajax({
                          type: "GET",
                          url: "test.php",
                          data: { name :$("#name").val() ,                }
                        }).done(function( msg ) {
                            alert("Ok");

                });


         });


     });
<?php
    if(isset($_GET["name"]))
    {
        echo "OK";

    }
    else
        echo "NO";

?>
<input type="text" id="name" />
<input type="button" id="btn_ok" />
```

`Ok alert is shown` but on the page echo `NO` instead of `OK`.

Comment: You are not getting the response anywhere.You ajax function will not refresh your frontend page...but will call the same page in backend. There your $_GET["name"] will be reconized, but your echo "OK" will never be visible if you are not getting the response.

Comment: If you got your answer then mark accepted or else post your solution. So it would be helpful to others. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

1.You should not call `same page` because ajax call will not execute (refresh) same page
   you have to call another page in which you have the php code

page1.php

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $("#btn_ok").click(function(){
          $.ajax({
              type: "GET",
              url: "page2.php",
              data: { name :$("#name").val() ,                }
          }).done(function( msg ) {
                //alert("Ok")
                alert(msg); //You have need a change here to see 
                            //response from page2.php
          });


     });
 });

     <input type="text" id="name" />
     <input type="button" id="btn_ok" />
```

page2.php

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET["name"]))
    {
        echo "OK";
    }
    else
        echo "NO";
?>
```

2.You did not show your msg in ajax done function

Use:

```
 alert(msg);
```

Instead of

```
  alert("Ok");
```

Answer (score 1):

You are doing AJAX call to same page, which means you get the content of the same page as a response and it will be in your `msg` string or when you use `success` function then also you get it.

And in that response you will get `OK` displayed.

AJAX is actually give you response what that page suppose to send content to browser. So if you are planning to display `OK` in page then you have to load this page with a query string parameter.

To display OK on page you should type following in your browser's addressbar.
`http://YOUR_PAGE_URL?name=anything`

Please [click here](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_intro.asp) to see more details about AJAX.